# Alexa (Smart Home Skill) to determine if device is offline.

Tags: aws-lambda, iot, alexa-skills-kit, aws-iot

I had created a simple Smart Home Skill for Alexa and I had successfully connected the skill to my device using AWS IoT but I can't figure out how I can make Alexa determine whether the device is offline or online. For example if I ​ask alexa to turn on the device, and if the the power of the device is off or the device is disconnected from the internet, I want Alexa to say the device is not responding. I can't think of a way, could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing a Smart Home skill then the responses that Alexa says are built into the Alexa service. So if you send back an "ENDPOINT_UNREACHABLE" response she is going to say "xxx is not responding" which is the built in response for that error type. If on the other hand your'e building a Custom skill then the responses are entirely up to you.
see:
https://github.com/alexa/alexa-smarthome/issues/19